# mongoid rails mongodb data not cleaning up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, activemodel

> Rails 3.2.1
>
> app name: demo
>
> database: mongoDB with mongoid

I have this scaffolding set up in rails 3.2.1: localhost:3000/pages,

and I have these fields: title, content.

I have already filled in 3 rows of data to each field.

The problem is: after deleting the app(by removing the root folder) and creating the same app name(demo) with the same scaffolding(pages), those 3 rows of data remain showing up which I don't want anymore.

Can anyone how to clean the database up?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database exists outside your application, so deleting your application will not affect it. To empty or delete it you need to use the mongo command line or another mongo tool. Open up a terminal / command prompt and type:

```
mongo
```

And you should get the mongo command line. Switch to the DB for your app (it will most likely be of the form `[app_name]_[environment]`:

```
use demo_development
```

And use the dropDatabase command:

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

Comment: It works, however, I wonder if mongoDB + mongoid can run rake db:reset to solve this problem.

Comment: `rake --tasks` in a mongomapper project indicates you could use `rake db:drop` or `rake db:reseed` for similar purpose. Don't have a mongoid project to hand though. Worth trying `rake --tasks` though to find out!

Answer (score 5):

the simplest way that i'm aware of is

```
rake db:mongoid:drop
```

as others said, you can go to rake --tasks and see it as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick snippet of how you can define a task, called db_reset, in your application namespace. It will drop both system and Mongo DBs given that MongoId gem is properly installed

**lib/tasks/app_name.rake:**

```
namespace Rails.application.class.parent do
  desc 'Drops and recreates both Mongo and system databases for the current environment and loads the seeds.'
  task db_reset: :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:mongoid:purge'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke
  end
end
```